# How does memory usage in Windows affect performance

Tags: windows, macos, memory, memory-management, memory-bandwidth

I'm running windows 10 with 4GBs of DDR3 1066 on Intel second generation i5 mobile architecture.

I come from a OSX background mostly and memory has always been a concern for me because I prefer to have many tabs open. I noticed on OSX that the memory usage didn't relate that much to the performance of the applications so long as it wasn't fully saturated but easily on my iMac I can run 80% of memory and find no noticeable lag or stuttering. However on Windows I'm finding memory to be the major bottleneck in my system, I understand that upgrading to 8 or 16GBs of memory would be the upgrade path for me. However I would love to understand why my system slows down noticeably when I saturate 80% of the memory unlike OSX that seems to handle it just fine. Is it a bandwidth limitation? I know that Windows NT and Darwin are completely different Kernels and I would love to be educated in exactly how that affects the same usage scenario so differently.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Sorry, StackOverflow is not the place for subjective questions on the relative merits of operating systems, especially when one of them is closed source. Here's a little humour instead... https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Windows

Comment: I don't see how my comment would be subjective, it's very specific in what I'm asking and I'm experiencing issues I haven't on my old operating system. If my question is too taxing for you, which I don't see how from your profile then why not offer me some sources to find out? BTW there's plenty of posts on here in regards to Windows, IOS and other closed sourced systems. The only reason OSX is partially open source is because Apple didn't have the expertise to get OS9 stable.